# SQLIte group by issue

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I have a problem with an SQLite query that is designed to return information about each album record for artists in my database table which is called Tracks. The query works fine if all the album names are unique but if I have an album name that is duplicated, for example many artists have albums called 'Greatest Hits', then I find that I get the same album artwork for every artist with a 'Greatest Hits' album name.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT artistName, trackName, trackPath, imagePath, year, albumName, bpm, genre1, genre2, genre3 
FROM Tracks WHERE genre1='Pop' or genre2='Pop' or genre3='Pop' 
GROUP BY albumName 
ORDER BY artistName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 GROUP BY albumName
```

to

```
 GROUP BY artistName, albumName
```

The original `GROUP BY` clause tells the system to "roll up" the data so there's only one line per albumName.  You really want one line per unique albumName / artistName combination.